# Save email attachment's link in android database downloaded by javamail

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I want to store all emails read by javamail so that next time only recent emails requires to download.All email fields are look simple to save in database except attachments.The bodypart of attahment returns inputstream instead of filepath.
My question is how to save attachment links for each email so that it can be download only when user wants.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this easier: If somebody wants to download the attachment just reconnect to the server and search for the given email, then download the attachment. So you don't need to store a link or anything in the database. Searching for a mail can be done by using `SearchTerms` an example for that can be found [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/using-javamail-for-searching-e-mail-messages).

Answer (score 0):

Attachments aren't files or links unless you turn them into files or links.

If you're writing a web user interface to email, you'll generally want to leave all the message data in the email server and fetch it from there when needed.  Depending on your user requirements, you might want to copy the messages from a "remote" email server to a "local" email server.

If you're determined to store all this information in a database, you're going to have to decide whether to store arbitrarily large attachments as BLOBs in the database, store them somewhere else (in the filesystem?), or leave them in the original email server and fetch them on demand.

Your web application will need to "create" a URL that represents each attachment, and when it gets a request for the URL it will need to interpret it and find the attachment wherever you decided to store it.  There's probably 100 ways to do this, and probably 90 of them are insecure, so be careful.